# PyTorch Loaders : Retrieving original test set and set of predictions for a deep model running on batches

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm training a multi-task deep learning model in `PyTorch` for a multi-regression problem. In particular, I have two targets and I'm having issues about retrieving them from the test_loader.

If I retrieve just one batch, what I obtain is this:

```
for data in test_loader:
     break

>>data.y #I'm using PyTorch Geometric and this returns target values

  [tensor([2.9700e-01, 1.8467e+00, 3.3684e+00, 3.8116e+00, 2.1730e-01, 5.5520e-01,
     7.3400e-02, 6.7590e-01, 5.3810e-01, 2.4115e+00, 6.1850e-01, 1.9349e+00,
     1.0159e+00, 1.1960e-01, 2.9608e+00, 1.1410e+00, 1.1750e-01, 3.0245e+00,
     3.4690e-01, 9.4170e-01, 8.6340e-01, 4.9826e+00, 8.9060e-01, 2.7065e+00,
     3.1614e+00, 2.0877e+00, 1.7380e+00, 2.6640e+00, 1.3882e+00, 8.0730e-01,
     2.6480e+00, 4.9870e-01, 5.4130e-01, 4.5343e+00, 2.6000e-03, 2.2055e+00,
     2.6452e+00, 3.1537e+00, 2.7212e+00, 4.4586e+00, 5.3340e-01, 1.0260e-01,
     3.8350e-01, 1.1600e-02, 1.4039e+00, 3.0600e+00, 4.8800e-02, 3.4395e+00,
     3.4467e+00, 4.9220e+00, 2.5419e+00, 1.8968e+00, 4.0945e+00, 2.6912e+00,
     1.2257e+00, 2.4072e+00, 3.0066e+00, 2.8466e+00, 2.3789e+00, 1.7575e+00,
     2.6239e+00, 5.6946e+00, 1.3764e+00, 4.7800e-02, 1.7183e+00, 1.5300e+00,
     8.5700e-01, 4.1565e+00, 4.5367e+00, 9.7040e-01, 2.9508e+00, 5.6663e+00,
     4.8030e-01, 5.0944e+00, 2.6179e+00, 2.8660e-01, 2.7508e+00, 1.6350e-01,
     6.9520e-01, 4.2832e+00, 9.3240e-01, 5.7414e+00, 1.1040e-01, 6.6690e-01,
     2.8895e+00, 2.9176e+00, 4.2810e-01, 5.2340e+00, 2.2622e+00, 3.2822e+00,
     4.6950e-01, 3.0513e+00, 3.9308e+00, 3.6964e+00, 2.0200e-02, 2.3557e+00,
     1.7065e+00, 2.8084e+00, 2.2530e+00, 4.3140e-01, 4.2487e+00, 4.2352e+00,
     2.2331e+00, 5.1698e+00, 4.0534e+00, 4.5324e+00, 4.1176e+00, 9.7360e-01,
     2.6766e+00, 4.7660e+00, 4.3731e+00, 2.1380e-01, 5.1878e+00, 3.0986e+00,
     5.8438e+00, 3.3690e+00, 3.6450e+00, 1.7497e+00, 4.3989e+00, 3.0263e+00,
     4.8384e+00, 4.3009e+00, 5.0180e-01, 1.3067e+00, 1.0911e+00, 5.1182e+00,
     4.2368e+00, 2.9340e+00]),
 tensor([-3.2216, -2.0006, -0.8724, -0.7857, -2.0937, -0.5880, -0.1444, -1.2542,
         -1.4671, -1.8303, -0.4976, -1.7154, -0.4975, -0.3465, -3.2251, -0.9821,
         -3.4257, -0.8081, -0.8262, -0.7048, -0.9562, -1.6014, -0.9571, -2.6037,
         -2.9677, -1.5079, -1.5834, -1.6801, -2.4680, -3.5596, -1.8807, -0.8356,
         -0.4993, -3.2280, -0.2746, -2.7333, -0.5740, -3.1329, -1.3730, -2.9125,
         -3.0086, -1.7985, -0.5292, -2.1010, -1.3797, -0.6524, -1.5601, -1.5005,
         -1.3369, -1.2464, -0.4897, -2.7310, -0.6254, -3.6283, -2.2886, -0.5919,
         -2.7681, -1.4977, -3.1605, -2.8174, -1.2291, -1.6025, -0.2486, -2.6170,
         -0.7761, -0.8276, -0.1415, -2.8051, -1.9874, -0.5155, -1.5940, -2.6758,
         -1.4691, -3.1783, -0.2966, -2.3155, -0.8844, -2.2093, -0.4627, -3.3262,
         -1.5778, -2.8662, -0.2760, -0.6699, -3.4056, -0.5907, -0.7972, -1.7826,
         -2.1572, -1.5537, -1.8523, -2.3121, -0.4772, -3.3559, -2.4694, -1.5811,
         -1.6458, -2.1036, -2.0809, -1.3649, -0.6173, -1.7415, -2.0036, -2.9653,
         -3.1574, -2.6495, -1.6283, -0.4403, -2.4322, -3.6548, -3.0187, -0.2075,
         -2.9463, -2.8336,  0.0300, -1.7765, -2.1068, -3.1375, -3.3158, -3.0454,
         -3.6105, -0.6832, -2.2353, -1.6552, -1.5867, -3.2761, -3.3904, -1.6116])]
```

So `data.y` is just a list of two  `torch.tensor` and each element in the list has shape `data.y[0].shape` = `data.y[1].shape` = `torch.Size([128])`

***First question:*** How can I retrieve my entire test set?

I would like to get a final tensor of size `[n_entries_test_set, 2]` having all the entries in my original test_set before having created the test_loader for pytorch (each entries has two associated targets).

***Second question:*** How can I obtain a full set of predictions with my model?

Similarly as before, if i take a single batch of data by doing

```
for data in test_loader:
     break
```

then by executing `model.forward(data)` I get:

```
tensor([[ 0.0286, -0.2509],
        [ 0.0287, -0.2527],
        [ 0.0279, -0.2500],
        [ 0.0268, -0.2472],
        [ 0.0280, -0.2508],
        [ 0.0272, -0.2486],
        [ 0.0244, -0.2413],
        [ 0.0275, -0.2486],
        [ 0.0292, -0.2534],
        [ 0.0300, -0.2560],
        [ 0.0282, -0.2504],
        [ 0.0266, -0.2469],
        [ 0.0272, -0.2494],
        [ 0.0273, -0.2488],
        [ 0.0251, -0.2422],
        [ 0.0269, -0.2472],
        [ 0.0258, -0.2438],
        [ 0.0280, -0.2503],
        [ 0.0275, -0.2495],
        [ 0.0299, -0.2555],
        [ 0.0278, -0.2493],
        [ 0.0266, -0.2467],
        [ 0.0277, -0.2505],
        [ 0.0277, -0.2496],
        [ 0.0266, -0.2469],
        [ 0.0251, -0.2425],
        [ 0.0270, -0.2468],
        [ 0.0288, -0.2525],
        [ 0.0274, -0.2491],
        [ 0.0279, -0.2494],
        [ 0.0266, -0.2465],
        [ 0.0269, -0.2466],
        [ 0.0247, -0.2419],
        [ 0.0268, -0.2483],
        [ 0.0268, -0.2464],
        [ 0.0284, -0.2519],
        [ 0.0271, -0.2477],
        [ 0.0274, -0.2490],
        [ 0.0291, -0.2529],
        [ 0.0287, -0.2526],
        [ 0.0272, -0.2480],
        [ 0.0266, -0.2471],
        [ 0.0223, -0.2357],
        [ 0.0280, -0.2501],
        [ 0.0275, -0.2487],
        [ 0.0282, -0.2507],
        [ 0.0273, -0.2489],
        [ 0.0265, -0.2464],
        [ 0.0293, -0.2538],
        [ 0.0277, -0.2491],
        [ 0.0289, -0.2526],
        [ 0.0261, -0.2456],
        [ 0.0271, -0.2469],
        [ 0.0255, -0.2432],
        [ 0.0263, -0.2457],
        [ 0.0259, -0.2450],
        [ 0.0279, -0.2494],
        [ 0.0268, -0.2460],
        [ 0.0248, -0.2409],
        [ 0.0290, -0.2529],
        [ 0.0281, -0.2504],
        [ 0.0286, -0.2518],
        [ 0.0262, -0.2474],
        [ 0.0259, -0.2446],
        [ 0.0258, -0.2447],
        [ 0.0268, -0.2480],
        [ 0.0274, -0.2486],
        [ 0.0278, -0.2501],
        [ 0.0268, -0.2460],
        [ 0.0276, -0.2487],
        [ 0.0284, -0.2511],
        [ 0.0283, -0.2510],
        [ 0.0291, -0.2536],
        [ 0.0284, -0.2510],
        [ 0.0274, -0.2483],
        [ 0.0258, -0.2447],
        [ 0.0273, -0.2479],
        [ 0.0293, -0.2544],
        [ 0.0272, -0.2479],
        [ 0.0268, -0.2474],
        [ 0.0274, -0.2482],
        [ 0.0276, -0.2492],
        [ 0.0265, -0.2457],
        [ 0.0249, -0.2417],
        [ 0.0258, -0.2448],
        [ 0.0272, -0.2483],
        [ 0.0296, -0.2538],
        [ 0.0288, -0.2527],
        [ 0.0290, -0.2527],
        [ 0.0257, -0.2437],
        [ 0.0257, -0.2441],
        [ 0.0281, -0.2507],
        [ 0.0280, -0.2503],
        [ 0.0243, -0.2413],
        [ 0.0260, -0.2446],
        [ 0.0253, -0.2426],
        [ 0.0240, -0.2402],
        [ 0.0293, -0.2543],
        [ 0.0261, -0.2455],
        [ 0.0262, -0.2446],
        [ 0.0265, -0.2460],
        [ 0.0298, -0.2546],
        [ 0.0282, -0.2502],
        [ 0.0281, -0.2509],
        [ 0.0278, -0.2499],
        [ 0.0286, -0.2517],
        [ 0.0280, -0.2497],
        [ 0.0265, -0.2457],
        [ 0.0269, -0.2471],
        [ 0.0249, -0.2431],
        [ 0.0287, -0.2520],
        [ 0.0311, -0.2579],
        [ 0.0289, -0.2524],
        [ 0.0257, -0.2443],
        [ 0.0275, -0.2482],
        [ 0.0284, -0.2513],
        [ 0.0270, -0.2474],
        [ 0.0246, -0.2417],
        [ 0.0270, -0.2477],
        [ 0.0269, -0.2482],
        [ 0.0267, -0.2477],
        [ 0.0289, -0.2517],
        [ 0.0263, -0.2455],
        [ 0.0285, -0.2521],
        [ 0.0295, -0.2540],
        [ 0.0266, -0.2471],
        [ 0.0267, -0.2465],
        [ 0.0271, -0.2478]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
```

and these are predictions of my model for a single batch of data. How can I retrieve an entire set of predictions for all the batches?

What I want to do is simply having a final set of predictions and set of original test_values to perform some standard metrics and see how my model is performing on new unseen data.

Many thanks, and let me know if any additional details may be required for my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this question correct, all you want is just one *batch* containing your *entire dataset*.

You can tell the `DataLoader` exactly that.

```
test_set = MyDataset(...) # your Dataset instance
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=len(test_set), ...)
```

Since you are loading all your test set, be careful not to exceed your available memory.